# Clean implementation of "decision matrix"

Tags: python, matrix

I am trying to find a clean solution to implement a basic decision matrix in python. I have 8 sensors that monitor an installation, and based on the state of these 8 sensors, I need to activate some relays.

My decision matrix looks like (S are sensors and R are R):

```
S1   S2   S3   S4   S5   S6   S7   S8   R1   R2   R3
0    1    0    0    1    1    0    1    0    0    1
1    0    1    0    0    1    1    0    1    1    1
0    1    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0
...
```

Currently the only implementation that I see, is a suite a if/elif statements for each row of my descision matrix like:

```
if S1==0 and S2==1 and S3==0 and S4==0 and S5==1 and S6==1 and S7==0 and S8==1:
    relay_state('R1', 0)
    relay_state('R2', 0)
    relay_state('R3', 1)
elif ...
```

This will definitely work, but I wonder if there is a cleaner way to implement this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use a dictionary of tuple

```
matrix = {
   (0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1):(0,0,1),
   (1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0):(1,1,1),
   (0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1):(0,1,0),

}
S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6,S7,S8 = 0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1
R1,R2,R3=matrix[S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6,S7,S8]
print (R1,R2,R3)

$python test.py
(0, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use list and compare lists:

```
if sensors == [0,1,0,1, ....]:
```

Even more efficient notations - if your handlers are functions, you may use a dictionary

```
decision_matrix = { (0,1,1,... ): some_handler, ... }
...
decision_matrix[sensors]()
```

Comment: `if sensors = ...` -> `if sensers == ...`

Comment: This is also a nice way of solving the problem. However, in my case, with a decision matrix of 8!, I would have to define 3! handlers. With the first solution, I only need one, that receive the three states of the relays.